# in my AMPL model its came out with Syntax Error

Tags: optimization, model, syntax-error, constraints, ampl

I use AMPL for my thesis anybody can help me? it is always come out with "error syntax" in constraint area. Anybody can help this?
I hope anybody can help my model, cause its for my thesis.

```
#VARIABLE
var Allocated {I,D,T} integer;              # allocated to group i in district d in time period t (y_idt)
var Stored {D,T}integer;                    # stored in district d warehouse in time period t (w_dt)
var Shipped {K,D,T} integer;                # shipped from distribution center k to district d warehouse in time-period t (x_kdt)
var Distribution_Center_set_up {K} binary;  # 0/1 if distribution center k is set up / don't set up (omega_k)
var miu integer;                            # new free variable

#OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
maximize Z: miu

#CONSTRAINT
subj to Newcon {i in I, d in D, t in T}: 
    miu <= Allocated [i,d,t] / total_demand [i,d];
    
subj to con_2 {i in I, d in D}: 
    sum {t in T} Allocated[i,d,t] >= coverage_rate[i] * total_demand[i,d];
    
subj to con_3 {d in D, t in {1}}: 
    sum {DistributionCenter} Shipped[k,d,t] - sum {GroupType} Allocated;
    
subj to con_4 {d in D, t in T diff {1}}: 
    sum {DistributionCenter} Shipped[k,d,t] - sum {GroupType} Allocated; 
    
subj to con_5 {k in K, t in T}: 
    sum {DemandPoint} Shipped[k,d,t] <= the_max_capacity[k,t];
    
subj to con_6 {k in K, d in D, t in T}:
    Shipped[k,d,t] * Distribution_Center_set_up [k];
    
subj to con_7: 
    sum {DistributionCenter} cost_of_setting_up[k] * Distribution_Center_set_up[k] 
        + sum {DistributionCenter,DemandPoint,TimePoint} per_dose_purchasing_cost * Shipped[k,d,t] 
            + sum {DistributionCenter,DemandPoint,TimePoint}  per_dose_transportation_cost[k,d] * Shipped[k,d,t] 
                + sum {DemandPoint,TimePeriode} per_dose_holding_cost[d] * Stored[d,t] <= budget;
```

Answer (score 0):

`subj to` is not a valid keyword for declaring constraints in AMPL. Use either `subject to` or the shorter version `s.t.`

However, if that is your whole program, it is missing the set declarations (`I`, `D`, `T` and `K`).

If you are new to AMPL, you may want to read some AMPL introduction, such as [this](https://pifop.com/help/ampl_programs.html). There is a section on constraint declaration [here](https://pifop.com/help/ampl_model_entities.html#Declaring%20Constraints).